# How to distribute / Where to store keys that applications need to access HashiCorp Vault

Tags: spring, security, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

We want to use HashiCorp Vault to save the passwords used by our applications.

What is not clear to me is, how to distribute/ where to store the keys our applications need to access the vault in a secure way.

I think this issue is not addressed by the vault documentation. At least, 
I couldn't find it. But clearly, it should by a problem every vault user has to handle.

Can someone give me a hint or provide an external tutorial, please?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to figure out is what Authentication method is available to you.

https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/index.html

For example, if you are running your app in AWS, you could be using [iam](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/aws.html) to authenticate. In this case, you dont need to provide anything to your application as its handled behind the scenes from Vault and AWS.

Another way would be [tokens](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/token.html) authentication where you'd need to provide your application a valid Vault token so that it can be used to get credentials.

[This](https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/security/iam-secure-intro) has more information about auth.